# How to list down mat files with a specific prefix name?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matlab-guide

I have a folder of images saved as `.mat` files files with the following names:

`image-001-001.mat,image-001-002.mat,......., image-001-102.mat, image-002-001.mat,image-002-002.mat, ....,image-002-090.mat, etc.`

I want to group the file names for each prefix. For example, list down all files that starts with `image-001-` prefix and list all images with `image-002-` and etc. for all files in the folder. I need the images of each group separately and do some processing on them.

Could someone please give some hints how can I do it?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

See the [documentation for `dir`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dir.html), specifically the mention of *wildcards*.

You can get a list of `.mat` files which start with `image-001` using

```
files_001 = dir('C:\myfolder\image-001*.mat');
% or if it's in the current directory then simply
% files_001 = dir('image-001*.mat');
```

To loop over several prefixes, you could use

```
prefixes = {'image-001', 'image-002', 'image-003'};
files = cell(numel(prefixes), 1);
for p = 1:numel(prefixes)
    files{p} = dir([prefixes{p}, '*.mat']);
end
```

---

Aside:

If your prefixes really are that similar / ordered, there are many ways (e.g. using `strcat`) to quickly make the prefixes cell array.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but the files name are not in order and I have quite a lot of them. How can I extract every single prefix?

Comment: What's the criteria for a prefix? Like are they all of the form `image-XXX` and you want to **1.** get all prefixes in a directory then **2.** Group all files in that directory by their prefix?

Comment: Yes, exactly. images should be grouped by `image-XXX` prefix

Comment: You may want to use `unique` on all names returned by `dir` which have been truncated to the first 10 characters

Answer (score -1):

YOu can pick all the images with start with image-001-xxx.mat as below:

```
files1 = dir('image-001*') ;
```